# Is there any research on the behavior of lists in rich text editors?

Tags: user-expectation, text-editor, structure

Lists involve a number of behaviors which seem inconsistent among most popular rich text editors in the market (Medium, Word, Google Docs, CKEditor, Froala, Wordpress classic, Wordpress Gutenberg, etc).

For example:

- What should happen when a user presses `Enter` on empty item that is also the last item in the list?
- What should happen when the user presses `Backspace` and the cursor is at the start of a list item?
- What should happen when user presses `Backspace` on a paragraph before a list?
- Etc.

Is there any research on these?

Comment: If you could do the research and define a standard for developers to use and achieve consistency (and whatever other benefits you can bring), I'm sure the world would be grateful!

Comment: What search terms did you use while searching for research, for example from Google Scholar. There is no need for us to duplicate the work you've already done.

Comment: I've never used Google Scholar before and didn't know there was UX information there. Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into that and post an answer if I find related info.

Comment: Inconsistencies among applications in the same category is not a new thing in IT, since standards and best practices often are in the context of the history and various business and technical constraints under which is was developed. What is your specific interest in finding this information out?

Answer (score 1):

The comparison between rich text editors in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors) only touches on the basic features, and there are some articles written by various developers of the rich text editors comparing certain features to other popular editors like this one for [text modification](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/text-modification/), so there is probably more out there for you to piece things together.

But this is a question that you can actually go and do the research to get the answer if you want, even though it might have changed somewhat since you first asked the question.